# How can I create and format chart legend depending on a variable being true?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I need to add a legend to the chart and format it at the bottom right of the chart if isLegend = True

```
With Monthly
    If isLegend = True Then .HasLegend = True
    .HasTitle = True
    If isTitle = True Then .ChartTitle.Text = Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `legend.position` property, to set the position of the legend, see [legend position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.legend.position).

To set the label for a series you use `series.HasDataLabels = True`, see [series datalabels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.hasdatalabels).

```
' to include the data label (n refers to the series here)
Charts(i).SeriesCollection(n).HasDataLabels = True
'Sets position to bottom of chart
Charts(i).legend.position = xlLegendPositionBottom
```

You then only have to edit your with blocks a bit

As a seperate note your if statements don't seem to have an `end if`